# 3rd person plural for "geschehen"?

Tags: verb, conjugation

A book of mine says that **geschehen** is only used in the 3rd person singular, thus `es geschieht`, `es geschah` or `es ist geschehen`.

But, since this verb translates as "to happen" or "to occur", can't it be used in plural conjugation?

If I want to say "things happen", must I find an alternative to "*Sachen geschehen*"?

Comment: It's always wise to look in another book, too.

Comment: *geschehen* can be used in the plural, but you cannot translate a saying word for word. *Sachen geschehen* is not an appropriate translation for *things happen*.

Answer (score 1):

No, in my opinion there is no need to search further,

"`Sachen geschehen`" or "`Sachen passieren"` is the correct translation for "things happen"